# Signals and slots in PyQt

Tags: qt, pyqt

In the past I've had some experience of Qt in C++. I've now started using PyQt, and finding it a bit bewildering. There doesn't seem to be any definitive source of documentation, apart from a small amount at Riverbank. I guess the first thing I'd like to know is that there's an initial hump with PyQt, and it does get easier. [**Edit:** The main problem I was having was due to a typo - `init` not `__init__`. I'm not finding it so hard now :P]

The [PyQt docs talk about new style signals and slots](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) for PyQt, as well as old style. They suggest that the new style is better, but I was wondering if that is what most users of PyQt do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is. New syntax is more clear, so why not?
Note, that when you trying to connect slots by name, you must call connectSlotsByName explicitly, since there no preprocessor that will work before execution and connect them.

PS: Beside, C++ syntax for signal/slot connnection is just ugly, and old PyQt syntax was pretty similar without any reason, so I was glad to see this change in PyQt.

PS2: There was the question here recently about this, check it out.

Comment: oops :) It wasn't russian, just a typo. It was 'out.' in russian charmap.

Answer (score 0):

**For reference see:** *[**PyQt Class Reference**](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/classes.html)* - it's quite comprehensive and goes into details with examples. Most of the examples are in C++ and although I'm something of a Python newbee, I didn't find it difficult to translate into Python.

If you're an experienced developer and starting to use Python and PyQt, this is a pretty good book - about the only full scale book on the subject that I know of: *[**Rapid GUI Programming with Python and Qt.**](http://www.qtrac.eu/pyqtbook.html)*

**Signals and Slots:** I always use the new syntax for signals and slots in PyQt, which is simple and elegant - much more 'pythonic'. PyQt is great, but in many respects it's still very C++ like - the more they do to 'pythonate' it, the better.